# Building new directory and pushing files  in Android

Tags: android

I have code that I know worked in another project of mine to create a new folder if it didn't already exist and place files from my project into it. But in my new project the code does nothing. What am i doing wrong?

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "testing");
            directory.mkdirs();

        File directory2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "CandooData" + File.separator + "Meds");
        if (!(directory2.isDirectory())) {
            directory2.mkdirs();
        }
        File directory3 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "CandooData" + File.separator + "Meds");
        String[] files;
        if (directory3.isDirectory()) {
            files = directory3.list();
            if (files.length == 0) {
                // directory is empty
                CopyAssets("medsxml", "/Meds");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Below is briefly example**

```
 File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Trip");
        if(!folder.exists()){
            folder.mkdir();
        }
           File newxmlfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Trip/"+ RecordID +".xml");
           try{
               newxmlfile.createNewFile();
           }catch(IOException e){

           }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. See the log via logcat.
2. It's possible that you've missed the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.
3. mkdirs() will work just fine, not worse than mkdir().

Comment: I've been looking at the log and there are no errors or anything, I do have that permission and I tried both. I thought maybe i had the location wrong but i tried changing it multiple times but still nothing. I feel like I'm going insane. Im doing this on my Transformer tablet if it makes a difference

Answer (score 1):

use this  **directory.mkdir();** instead of this  **directory.mkdirs()**;

Answer (score 0):

I am using this below method to make directory and save the file in to it.

```
private static File APP_FILE_PATH = new File("/sdcard/SpeechTutor");

 p_file_Side_Slow = new File("/sdcard/SpeechTutor/P_SideMovieSlow.mp4");
        p_file_Side_Medium = new File("/sdcard/SpeechTutor/P_SideMovieMedium.mp4");
        p_file_Side_Fast = new File("/sdcard/SpeechTutor/P_SideMovieFast.mp4");

        p_file_Front_Slow = new File("/sdcard/SpeechTutor/P_FrontMovieSlow.mp4");
        p_file_Front_Medium = new File("/sdcard/SpeechTutor/P_FrontMovieMedium.mp4");
        p_file_Front_Fast = new File("/sdcard/SpeechTutor/P_FrontMovieFast.mp4");

 if((!(p_file_Side_Slow.exists())) || (!(p_file_Side_Medium.exists())) || (!(p_file_Side_Fast.exists())) 
                || (!(p_file_Front_Slow.exists()))|| (!(p_file_Front_Medium.exists()))||(!(p_file_Front_Fast.exists()))){
            ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();
            files.add("P_SideMovieSlow.mp4");
            files.add("P_SideMovieMedium.mp4");
            files.add("P_SideMovieFast.mp4");

            files.add("P_FrontMovieSlow.mp4");
            files.add("P_FrontMovieMedium.mp4");
            files.add("P_FrontMovieFast.mp4");
            new myAsyncTask().execute(files);
         }



// AsyncTass for the Progress Dialog and to do Background Process
    private class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<String>, Void, Void> {         
        ArrayList<String> files;         
        ProgressDialog dialog;         
        @Override         
        protected void onPreExecute() {             
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainScreenActivity.this, "Speech Tutor", "Loading...");         
        }         
        @Override         
        protected Void doInBackground(ArrayList<String>... params) {              
            files = params[0];             
            for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {                 
                copyFileFromAssetsToSDCard(files.get(i));                
            }             return null;         
        }         
        @Override         
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {             
            dialog.dismiss();   
//          myVideoThumbnail.setImageBitmap((Bitmap)ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(p_file_Side_Slow.getAbsolutePath(),MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND));
//          myVideoView.setVideoURI(p_uri_Side_Medium);
            setVideoURI(sideShow, frontshow, slowShow, mediumShow, fastShow);
        }      
    } 


// Function to copy file from Assets to the SDCard
    public void copyFileFromAssetsToSDCard(String fileFromAssets){
        AssetManager is = this.getAssets();
        InputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = is.open(fileFromAssets);
            FileOutputStream fos;
            if (!APP_FILE_PATH.exists()) {
                APP_FILE_PATH.mkdirs();
            }
            fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/SpeechTutor",fileFromAssets));
            byte[] b = new byte[8];
            int i;
            while ((i = fis.read(b)) != -1) {
                fos.write(b, 0, i);
            }
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

All Above code will save the file as background process.